# Avoiding Duplicate Dependency Resolution When Creating Multiple Microservices in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config, nestjs-microservice

In a NestJS project, I'm facing a challenge with duplicate dependency resolution when creating multiple microservices. The standard approach to initializing multiple microservices seems to re-instantiate dependencies for each one. How I can get rid of that?

Of course, I can use `amqplib` or something similar, but then `@MessagePattern({cmd:"something"})` and other native NestJS code won't work.

The same problem would be if you want to get some config from `ConfigModule` parameter in order to instantiate microservice. Because to resolve dependency of `ConfigModule` you need to create app instance first and then again instance for microservice.

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const appContext = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppModule);
  // OR: const appContext = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(AppModule);
  const configService = appContext.get(ConfigService);
  const microserviceOptions: MicroserviceOptions = {
    transport: Transport.RMQ,
    options: {
      urls: [configService.get<string>(ConfigPropertyNames.RABBITMQ_URI)],
      queue: QueueNames.AUTH_SERVICE_RPC,
      queueOptions: {
        durable: false
      },
    },
  }
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(AppModule, microserviceOptions);

  await app.listen();
  Logger.log(
    ` Application is running`
  );
}
```

```
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:58     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:58     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +13ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:58     LOG [InstanceLoader] CustomConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:58     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:58     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:58     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:58     LOG [InstanceLoader] LoggerModule dependencies initialized +69ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseCoreModule dependencies initialized +349ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +6ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongoDBModule dependencies initialized +1ms
2024-03-14 10:51:59 INFO : User service is being initialized
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application... +2ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +3ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [InstanceLoader] CustomConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [InstanceLoader] LoggerModule dependencies initialized +3ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseCoreModule dependencies initialized +303ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongoDBModule dependencies initialized +0ms
2024-03-14 10:51:59 INFO : User service is being initialized
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [InstanceLoader] AuthModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG [NestMicroservice] Nest microservice successfully started +357ms
[Nest] 23400  - 14.03.2024, 10:51:59     LOG  Application is running
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could take advantage of [Hybrid application support](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application) from NestJS.
Your code would become:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
const configService = appContext.get(ConfigService);
const microserviceOptions: MicroserviceOptions = {
    transport: Transport.RMQ,
    options: {
      urls: [configService.get<string>(ConfigPropertyNames.RABBITMQ_URI)],
      queue: QueueNames.AUTH_SERVICE_RPC,
      queueOptions: {
        durable: false
      },
    },
    inheritAppConfig: true // Note this extra config
}
const microservice = app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(microserviceOptions);

await app.startAllMicroservices();
await app.listen(3000);
```

---

Otherwise, recently NestJS has introduced [Conditional modules registration](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#conditional-module-configuration). You could create a `MicroserviceModule`, move all the interested modules inside of it, and register it based on a `ConfigService` variable (e.g. `isMicroservice`). You could use two different environment files for the two application but it can be tricky.

```
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot(), ConditionalModule.registerWhen(MicroserviceModule, 'USE_MICROSERVICE')],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

---

Finally, the simplest way would be to create a "dummy" `AppModule` that has only the `ConfigService` as imports, create `app` from it, and create `microservice` with your real `AppModule`

```
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot(),
})
export class AppConfigModule {}
@Module({
...yourAppModuleConfig
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const appContext = await NestFactory.createApplicationContext(AppConfigModule);
  // OR: const appContext = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(AppConfigModule);
  const configService = appContext.get(ConfigService);
  const microserviceOptions: MicroserviceOptions = {
    transport: Transport.RMQ,
    options: {
      urls: [configService.get<string>(ConfigPropertyNames.RABBITMQ_URI)],
      queue: QueueNames.AUTH_SERVICE_RPC,
      queueOptions: {
        durable: false
      },
    },
  }
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(AppModule, microserviceOptions);

  await app.listen();
  Logger.log(
    ` Application is running`
  );
}
```